# how to change contents in switch dynamicaly on mouse click?

Tags: jquery, html

this is my script,here I wonder insert all questions in switch function and I'll like to change it and then display each questions with mouse click,but only 1st question is displaying, other clicks are not changing..what should i need to change over here.

```js
window.onload = init;
var currentQuestion=1;
function init() {   
 switch (currentQuestion) {
   case 1: $('.question').html('what is your name?');
            break;
   case 2: $('.question').html('where are you from?');
            break;
   case 3: $('.question').html('what is your fav color?');
            break;
   case 4: $('.question').html('what is your fav flower?');
            break;
   case 5: $('.question').html('which is your native?');
            break;
        default: break;
    }
 }
 $("#next").click(function(){
 currentQuestion++;
 var before=currentQuestion-1;
 console.log(currentQuestion);
 console.log(before);
 //$("before").hide();
 });
```

```css
.next img,.prev img
{
width:100px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
}
.prev img
{left:115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question"></div>
<div class="input1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="next">
<img id="next" src ="images/next-button.png" />
</div>
<div class="prev">
<img src ="images/download.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="answer"></div>
```

Comment: sorry not from array,fron switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to call the function `init` after every click.

Pass argument as `currentQuestion` so that switch will work accordingly. To use `init` on `window.onload`, I am accepting argument as `currentQuestion`

```js
var currentQuestion = 1;
window.onload = function() {
  init(currentQuestion);
};


function init(currentQuestion) {
  switch (currentQuestion) {
    case 1:
      $('.question').html('what is your name?');
      break;
    case 2:
      $('.question').html('where are you from?');
      break;
    case 3:
      $('.question').html('what is your fav color?');
      break;
    case 4:
      $('.question').html('what is your fav flower?');
      break;
    case 5:
      $('.question').html('which is your native?');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
$("#next").click(function() {
  currentQuestion++;
  var before = currentQuestion - 1;
  init(currentQuestion);
});
```

```css
.next img,
.prev img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.prev img {
  left: 115px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question"></div>
<div class="input1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="next">
  <img id="next" src="images/next-button.png" />
</div>
<div class="prev">
  <img src="images/download.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="answer"></div>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `$("#next")` to `$(".next")` since your selector in your markup is a `class`. (because the image is not loaded with the id of next in the current markup)

You also have to call your `init();` function every time a click event happens to your next button.

The same thing needs to be done in your Previous button :).

I hope this has given you some Idea.

```js
window.onload = init;
var currentQuestion = 1;

function init() {
  switch (currentQuestion) {
    case 1:
      $('.question').html('what is your name?');
      break;
    case 2:
      $('.question').html('where are you from?');
      break;
    case 3:
      $('.question').html('what is your fav color?');
      break;
    case 4:
      $('.question').html('what is your fav flower?');
      break;
    case 5:
      $('.question').html('which is your native?');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

$(".next").click(function() {
  currentQuestion++;
  var before = currentQuestion - 1;
  init();
  console.log(currentQuestion);
  console.log(before);
  //$("before").hide();
});
```

```css
.next img,
.prev img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.prev img {
  left: 115px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question"></div>
<div class="input1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="next">
  <img id="next" src="images/next-button.png" />
</div>
<div class="prev">
  <img src="images/download.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="answer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vsogrimen... :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are not wrong, but I thought I might show you a possibly simpler way to do what you need.

The approach below is basically to..

- add all the questions, separated with a `|` character, as a data attribute on the question div itself
- add a counter stored as an attribute on the question div to keep up with the current index
- when a user clicks either a next or prev button, check if it was next or prev and add or subtract from the index accordingly
- display the question stored at the new index

A cool benefit of this approach is also that, if you need to, you can have multiple question elements on the same page without changing any code, just add the HTML

#### [Here is a fully commented jsFiddle explaining the code](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/y2qvb7zu/9/)

```js
$('.next, .prev').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $questionDiv=$this.prevAll('.question');
  var storedQuestions = $questionDiv.data('stored-questions').split('|');
  var cur = Number($questionDiv.data('current-question'));
  var setTo = $this.hasClass('next') ? cur+1 : cur-1;
  setTo = setTo > (storedQuestions.length-1) ? 0 : setTo < 0  ? (storedQuestions.length-1) : setTo; 
  $questionDiv.html(storedQuestions[setTo]).data('current-question',setTo);
});
```

```css
.next img,
.prev img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.prev img {
  left: 115px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" data-current-question="0" data-stored-questions="what is your name?|where are you from?|what is your fav color?|what is your fav flower?|which is your native?">what is your name?</div>
<div class="input1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="prev">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=48&txt=Prev&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
<div class="next">
  <img id="next" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=48&txt=Next&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
<div class="answer"></div>
```